# ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC EF One-to-Many and Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, many-to-many, one-to-many, asp.net-core-2.0

In the last days I have been working on the creation of a relationship between different classes. Unfortunately, I can't solve it, hopefully you can help me further. Below you can find the problem definition.

I have the following classes:

- **BaseEntity**
- **Product**
- **Category**
- **Tag**
- **ProductCategory**
- **ProductTag**

BaseEntity Class:

```
    public class BaseEntity 
    { 
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }

        public BaseEntity { }
    }
```

Product Class:

```
public class Product: BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }


    public long CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category MainCategory { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductSubCategory> ProductSubCategories { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductTag> ProductTags { get; set; }
}
```

Category Class:

```
public class Category : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductSubCategory> ProductSubCategories{ get; set; }

}
```

Tag Class:

```
public class Tag: BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductTag> ProductTags { get; set; }
}
```

ProductSubCategory Class:

```
public class ProductSubCategory : BaseEntity
{ 
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product{ get; set; }

    public long SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

ProductTag Class:

```
public class ProductTag: BaseEntity
{ 
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product{ get; set; }

    public long TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tags { get; set; }
}
```

A product has one main category. (one-to-many)
A product could have many subcategories. (many-on-many)
A product could have many tags. (many-on-many)

My class-Maps are like this:

ProductMap:

```
public ProductMap(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> entityBuilder)
{
        entityBuilder.HasOne(p => p.MainCategory)
            .WithMany(c => c.Products)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
}
```

ProductSubCategoryMap:

```
  public ProductSubCategoryMap(EntityTypeBuilder<ProductSubCategory> entityBuilder)
    {
        entityBuilder
        .HasKey(psc=> new { psc.ProductId, psc.CategoryId });

        entityBuilder
        .HasOne<Product>(psc => psc.Product)
        .WithMany(p => p.ProductSubCategories)
        .HasForeignKey(psc => psc.ProductId);

        entityBuilder
        .HasOne<Category>(psc=> psc.Category)
        .WithMany(sc => sc.ProductSubCategories)
        .HasForeignKey(psc => psc.CategoryId);;
    }
```

ProductTagMap:

```
  public ProductTagMap(EntityTypeBuilder<ProductTag> entityBuilder)
    {
        entityBuilder
            .HasKey(pt => new { pt.ProductId, pt.TagId});

        entityBuilder
            .HasOne<Product>(pt => pt.Product)
            .WithMany(p => p.ProductTags)
            .HasForeignKey(pt=> pt.ProductId);

        entityBuilder
            .HasOne<Tag>(pt => pt.Tag)
            .WithMany(t => t.ProductTags)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagId);
    }
```

How can I set:
One-to-many between Product(MainCategory) and Category. 
Many-on-many between Product(SubCategories) and Category 
Many-on-many between Product(Tags) and Tag.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A few questions first,  you are using code-first approach yes? As you are using the virtual navigation properties.  Just want to be sure.

Are you currently getting any errors, what have you tried,  what is failing?

Where you place the virtual property and not in the other model, that will give you a one-to-many relationship. If they are in both models you achieve the many-to- many relationship.

In Product class add

```
public virtual Catagory Catagory { get; set; }
```

If you need it to be a collection then add that before  like you have in your others and maybe name the ICollection Catagories instead of singular .

```
public virtual ICollection<Catagory> Catagories { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi BenCdev, thanks for your reply! Yes, I'm using code-first approach. 
At some moment, I had so many errors, that I decided to start with a new solution. I decided to remove to virtual and thus I followed your advice. Unfortunately, I can't test it, because I'm not be able to make migrations (I have 4 different projects, 3 class libraries: Data, Repository, Service and one Core MVC webapplication called Web). At this moment, I'm not be able to do the migrations in the Repository project (I moved default migration folder and classes to Repository).